# Getting dbpedia results with optional properties

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I'm building an app which shows information about entities of a given text. I'm using a sparqlwrapper library for Python to query DBpedia. I'm using the following code when I get a `Person` entity:

```
def get_person_data(einfo):
    data = {}
    try:
        uri = einfo['disambiguated']['dbpedia']

        sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
        query = u"""
        SELECT ?birthDate, ?birthName, ?birthPlace
        WHERE { <%s>
                dbpprop:birthDate ?birthDate ;
                dbpprop:birthName ?birthName ;
                dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace
        }
        """ % uri
        sparql.setQuery(query)
        sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
        results = sparql.query().convert()
```

The problem with this code is that when a field is missing in the DBpedia page, the results return nothing. It's difficult to know which properties are present in all the entities of a given type, so I'd like to define some desirable properties and then get the ones present. I tried querying with something like:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "New York"@en.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  OPTIONAL { 
  ?x dbpedia-owl:areaTotal ?areaTotal.
  ?x dbpprop:governor ?governor.
  ?x dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace.
  }
  FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
}
```

In this case, New York doesn't have a `birthPlace`, so I end up getting only the `abstract` information. I'd like to get `areaTotal` and `governor` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *entire* optional block either matches or it doesn't.  If you want to optionally match a few different things, you need multiple optional blocks, as in

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "New York"@en.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  OPTIONAL { ?x dbpedia-owl:areaTotal ?areaTotal. }
  OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:governor ?governor. }
  OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace. }
  FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?x%20rdfs%3alabel%20%22New%20York%22@en.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpedia-owl%3aabstract%20?abstract.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20?x%20dbpedia-owl%3aareaTotal%20?areaTotal.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20?x%20dbpprop%3agovernor%20?governor.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20?x%20dbpprop%3abirthPlace%20?birthPlace.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28?abstract%29%20=%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)